# How to get debian apt to find packages correctly to install sudo

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, package-management, apt-get

I've just installed debian 9 using the full disc image (debian-9.8.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1) to install on VirtualBox in a 64bit environment from a Windows 10 host. During the installation I unchecked the desktop environment and xfce checkboxes. I kept the utilities checkbox checked. I did this as I want to be left with a lightweight installation to use as a local server.

Trying to install the 'sudo' package using apt.

I have commented out the CD-rom source and added these sources to `/etc/apt/sources.list`;

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main non-free
```

I have then run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

Further to this is where I am encountering a problem. When I try to run `apt install sudo`, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sud is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or 
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sudo' has no installation candidate
```

I can see that this is true when I run `apt-cache policy sudo` as it shows me:

```
sudo:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: Hi Nath, Could you please paste the output of your `sources.list` file? I believe there is `main` component missing. I think you have `main` and `non-free` versions of `stretch-updates`, but not the `main` version for `stretch`.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus all of the uncommented lines of the ```sources.list``` file are in the question, regards

Comment: If that is all in your `sources.list`, you should add [lines](https://paste.debian.net/?show=1077148;lines=0) for `main` for `stretch` too. Then do an update upgrade followed by a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly - You may have some missing sources in your sources.list file.

Use  [Debian Sources List Generator](https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/) to automatically generate a list of sources and update your sources.list accordingly.